# jmeter resolve variables in csv at runtime

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I have a jmeter script that takes in input a Load CSV Test Data having this content:
[image]

The "generateToken" first API retrieves a token and store it in the "token" JSON Extractor variable.
The "myApiName" second API sends in the body request the value of "token" via ${token} variable

Running the script, Jmeter does not resolve the ${token} placeholder in "myApiName" request:

[image]

I've also used eval or evalVar or V functions in csv file without success. I can't use them in Jmeter.
I'm thinking to configure a Pre-Processor element to resolve all these occurrences using the replace mothod.
For example:

```
String s = "${apiRequestBody}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("${.*?}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);  
if(m.find())
   ${apiRequestBody}.replace(p, vars.get("p"))
```

Please could you help me to find the correct code to resolve all the occurrences or suggest me another way to do that?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) and you should be using it in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler's "Body Data" tab as:

```
${__eval(${apiRequestBody})}
```

[image]

I don't think you will be able to put the function into the CSV file.

> I can't use them in Jmeter

Why? The __eval() function is safe to use anywhere, it won't do any harm and corrupt anything.

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)

Comment: I hadn't thought to use the __eval() function to all the request (apiRequestBody) but to use it for token variable only. That's why I didn't want to use it.
Anyway I solved applying the function to all the request. Thanks a lot